# im trying to install flatpak on qemu utm ubuntu mac m1 jammy but i get errors

Tags: 22.04, qemu, flatpak

When I install flatpak (attempt to) I get these errors:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 flatpak : Depends: libmalcontent-0-0 (>= 0.6.0) but it is not installable
           Depends: libostree-1-1 (>= 2020.8) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have tried tutorials all over the internet, but I am stumped. Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Comment: Providing the actual command and full detail of the command which generated that error would allow more specific advice. Your issue is almost certainly related to a 3rd party source you've added thus I'd explore your prior commands too (*none of you provided details about*)  Your detail does ~match https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/flatpak  however we can't read messages when they're not provided (*including command which belongs in your question; I'd also suggest checking you get no warnings/errors when running `sudo apt update`*)

Comment: i got the entire terminal history if that helps

Comment: i did sudo apt update and apt list upgradable, sudo apt fix broken install

Comment: $ grep -ir "^deb" /etc/apt/ --include=*.list, sudo apt install flatpak,